# Getting number of rows/columns from csv file in R with condition

Tags: r, csv, read.table

I've got .csv file, with I read with command:

```
my_data <- read.csv("file_name")
```

It has a lot of columns, but I want to get number of rows, withc specific column condition, for example, number of rows, where value of column "VAL" is greater 20.
I've tried with:

```
k <-subset(my_data, my_data$VAL > 24)
length(k)
```

But it dosen't look correct. I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You don't need `my_data$VAL` inside `subset` ie. `k <- subset(my_data, VAL >24); nrow(k)`

Comment: You could use `sum(my_data$VAL > 24)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dim(k)` if you need to keep the data frame or `dim(subset(my_data, my_data$VAL > 24))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the number of such observations then I prefer simply summing a boolean vector. Possibly R's greatest strength is the vectorised operations such that `(df$y > 100)` will give you a vector indicating whether each individual observation is true or false. You can then sum this to get the total number that are true.

```
x <- 1:10000
y <- rnorm(1000,100,10)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y)) #create a dataframe

count <- sum(df$y > 100)
```